# Specified cast is not valid - ADO.net query

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I get this error specifically on this line: `_item.Views = (int)reader["views"];`
The "views" column in my db table is of type int. as you can see in the image below:

[image]

The object field I'm reading the data into is also of type int. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as this code was working before. I have been stuck on this for a while now, not able to figure out what to do.

Comment: I can see that `views` allow for null values. Are you sure you aren't getting a null?

Comment: ohh it is null. Is that why this error is happening?

Comment: Yes. `int` is not a nullable type. Either make `views` not nullable too, or cast the value to `int?`, or check for null before casting to `int`.